How can I check that for a quasi-compact morphism $f:Z\to X$, the kernel of $\mathcal{O}_X\to f_*\mathcal{O}_Z$ is quasi-coherent?

If $f:Z\rightarrow X$ is a quasi compact morphism of schemes and $\mathcal J  :=\ker(\mathcal O_X \rightarrow f_* \mathcal{O}_Z)$, then $(\operatorname{Supp}( \mathcal O_X/ \mathcal J)$,$i^{-1}(\mathcal O_X/\mathcal J))$ is a scheme. Where $i: Supp( \mathcal O_X/ \mathcal J)\rightarrow X$ denotes the inclusion map.

How to prove this statement? I think it is enough to check that the ideal sheaf $\mathcal J$ is quasi-coherent. That is, for any $D(g)\subset U=\operatorname{Spec} A$ affine open, we need to check $J(D(g))=I A_g$ where $I=\mathcal J(U)$. That is what I think :
$$\mathcal J(D(f))=\ker(\mathcal O_X(D(f))\rightarrow \mathcal O_Z(f^{-1}(D(f))))\\
=\ker(A_f\rightarrow \mathcal O_Z(\cup_{i=1}^nU_i))\\
=\ker(A_f\rightarrow  \mathcal O_Z(\cup_{i=1}^nU_i) \rightarrow \bigoplus_{i=1}^nB_{if_i})$$
The second "=" is because we assume $f$ is quasi compact and $D(f)$ is quasi compact, hence its preimage is quasi compact and hence can be covered by finitely many affine open $U_i=\operatorname{Spec} B_i$.
The last "=" is because for any sheaf $\mathscr F$ and for any open cover $U=\cup_i U_i$, the map $\mathscr F(U)\rightarrow \Pi_i\mathscr F(U_i)$ is always injecive. Hence, $\mathcal O_Z(\cup_{i=1}^nU_i) \rightarrow \Pi_{i=1}^n\mathcal O_Z(U_i)$ is injective and we can assume $U_i=D(f_i)$ are principal open for $f_i\in B_i$ then $\mathcal O_Z(U_i)=B_{i,f_i}$. We can replace product by direct sum since it is finite. Composing a injective map does not change the kernel.
Am I going in the right direction? I do not know how to continue, I am thinking maybe I am completely wrong.

Your latest edit is a little confusing since $f$ is the name of the map $Z\to X$ but then also gets used for some element of the ring $A$ (and it doesn't match the $g$ you use right before that).

Yes, the statement is correct and you're going in the right direction. First, closed subschemes of a scheme $X$ are in bijection with quasi-coherent sheaves of ideals on $X$ via the construction you describe in your post; next, a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on a scheme $X$ is quasi-coherent iff for every affine open $U=\operatorname{Spec} A \subset X$ and every $a\in A$ we have $\mathcal{F}(U)_a = \mathcal{F}(D(a))$, where $D(a)\subset U$. The proof of the first statement is standard; the proof of the second is not so hard but is less commonly written down, and follows directly from the statement that a sheaf is uniquely recoverable from its values on a basis.
So it suffices to show that for an affine open $U=\operatorname{Spec} A \subset X$ and an element $a\in A$, we have $\mathcal{J}(\operatorname{Spec} A)_a = \mathcal{J}(\operatorname{Spec} A_a)$. By definition, $\mathcal{J}(U)$ is the kernel of $\mathcal{O}_X\to (f_*\mathcal{O}_Z)(U) = \mathcal{O}_Z(f^{-1}(U))$, and as you've pointed out, we can use the fact that if $\{V_i = \operatorname{Spec} B_i\}_{i\in I}$ are an open cover of $f^{-1}(U)$, then the map $\mathcal{O}_Z(f^{-1}(U))\to \prod_i \mathcal{O}_Z(V_i)$ is an injection, so $\mathcal{J}(U)$ is the kernel of $\mathcal{O}_X(U) \to \prod_i \mathcal{O}_Z(V_i)$. Now localize at $a$: since $I$ may be taken finite, as $f$ is quasi-compact, localization commutes with products, and as we're looking at the values of the structure sheaf on affine open sets, we find that the localization of this morphism at $a$ is simply the natural map $\mathcal{O}_X(U_a) \to \prod_i \mathcal{O}_Z((V_i)_a)$. But that has kernel exactly $\mathcal{J}(U_a)$, so we have $\mathcal{J}(U)_a \cong \mathcal{J}(U_a)$, and we're done.
Another name for this result is "scheme-theoretic images of quasi-compact morphisms can be computed affine locally".

Thank you a lot. Your answer is helpful but I still do not fully understand your last part. Your idea is that the map $\mathscr O_X(U)\rightarrow \Pi _i \mathscr O_Z(V_i)$ localized at $a$ identifies with the map $\mathscr O_X(U_a)\rightarrow \Pi_i \mathscr O_Z((V_i)_a)$ hence they have the same kernel. I am confused about what $U_a$ andd $(V_i)_a$ mean. I guess $U_a:=SpecA_a$ but what does $(V_i)_a$ mean? Since $a$ is not necessarily an element in $B_i$,  I cannot localize $B_i$ at $a$.

@user11695417 You pretty much got there - for a scheme $S$ with a global section $\alpha\in\mathcal{O}S(S)$, $S\alpha$ is used to denote the open subscheme where $\alpha$ does not vanish on $S$. I was thinking this would be clearer than writing $D(a)$ since $D(a)$ depends on the ambient space, but if that would be clearer for you I could do that instead. And $a$ is not an element in $B_i$, but we localize at the image of $a$ in $B_i$, which is fine since the map $\operatorname{Spec} B_i\to\operatorname{Spec} A$ gives a map $A\to B_i$.
